# Having a hard time understanding MS Access backend technologies

Tags: ms-access, server

I want to clarify what I do understand first.

- We can store data on MS Acess itself but doing so will make the
  database usable in only one computer where the Access table is. This makes it difficult to share data
- We can create a SQL server to store database

My confusion is on some of the technicalities of the SQL server part

- Is ODBC just a connector for Access and SQL sever?
- Does VBA code differ if we have SQL server or not?
- Difference between SQL Server Management Studio vs ODBC database vs SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

First, on what you do understand:

- You can place the Access database on a network share, so it can be used from different computers.
- You can also place an Access database file containing just the tables ("the backend") on a network share and use linked tables in several "frontend" database files.

Now, on the things that confuse you:

- ODBC ("Open Database Connectivity") is a standardized technology that allows applications to access data from various sources. You can use an ODBC driver (for "SQL Server" in your case) to allow an Access frontend to work with data stored in a SQL Server database. The database tables from the backend can be linked into the frontend (as "linked tables") and then be used in the Access forms and reports just as if they were tables in the Access database.
- You will most probably not *need* to change your existent VBA code when using "linked tables" (unless you use some functionality that applies just to local tables). But for sure you *can* change some code or even move some routines into the backend database (as "stored procedures") and call them from your VBA code to improve performance.
- "SQL Server Management Studio" is a tool (**the** tool from Microsoft) that is used to manage all kind of objects on a SQL Server (databases, tables, views, stored procedures…). Also, it allows you to write and run SQL scripts and single SQL statements (like queries). It is a graphical user interface so manage SQL Server instances and everything that belomgs to databases using table or query designers, data grids and several property windows.

"SQL Server Management Studio" can be seen as a frontend, too, because behind the scene, it uses SQL commands to communicate with SQL Server. To manage the communication between the frontend "SQL Server Management Studio" and a backend (a SQL Server instance), it does not use ODBC but a newer technology named OLEDB.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have one more question. If ODBC is a connector which helps connect Access to an SQL database I dont't understand why we would use SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: ODBC is used to connect the SQL Server tables to the Access database as "linked tables". This is done to access the data in these tables, but it does not provide a means to add more tables to the database or edit the design of the existing tables. SQL Server Management Studio does, and it also allows you to manage all other aspects of the database server, for example to plan for automatic backups of the database.

Comment: sql management tools allow you to create tables, modify tables, and is VERY similar to the table designer in Access. When you use a external database (as opposed to the Access built in one), then you can't use the access designer tools to create, delete and manage those tables and the database. So while you can build forms, reports etc. in Access, you need SSMS to create the tables, design the tables etc. Same for MySQl. or some other database with Access. All the access code etc. is quite much the same, but to design tables and setup the database, you cant use Access to design the database.